# How to add lines to a CSV file without overwriting it

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

```
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");
foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
    fputcsv($file,explode(',',$email));
}
fclose($file);
```

The above code generates a CSV file. How can I update the CSV from the last recorded line without overwriting from the beginning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change `"w"` to `"a"` in the `fopen`. It changes "write" into "append".

"append" opens the file and writes at the end of the file, not from the beginning like "write".

i.e. change this line

`$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");`

to

`$file = fopen("contacts.csv","a");`